# Local homeomorphism from a locally Euclidean space implies Euclidean space

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to show that for $f:X \rightarrow Y$ local homeomorphism and surjective If $X$ is locally Euclidean so is $Y$.

From Local homeomorphism we have that there exists $V_{x}$ such that $f:V_{x} \rightarrow f(V_{x})$ where $y=f(x)$

But what If the neighbourhood $U_{x}$ from locally Euclidean is not contained in $V_{x}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great! Then take $U_x\cap V_x$.

Comment: Is It still homeomorphic to a ball?

Comment: What is your definition of a locally Euclidean space? One of the equivalent definitions is that it's a space $X$ such that for every $x\in X$ there exists an open set $U$ containing $x$ such that $U$ is homeomorphic to a Euclidean space (or to an open subset of a Euclidean space). $U_x\cap V_x$ is an open subset of $U_x$ which is homeomorphic to an open subset of a Euclidean space (by definition of $U_x$ I guess). So $U_x\cap V_x$ is homeomorphic to an open subset $W$ of a Euclidean space.

Comment: If your definition requires an open ball, it's ok. Take an open ball in $W$.

Comment: Not requiring an open ball, It is equivalent

Comment: I was stuck on seing It being open but i guees It is quite natural so

Comment: @DanielMoraes Just ask! What is it that you're not seing it being open? $U_x\cap V_x$? If so that's by the very definition of open sets.

Comment: Actually was having trouble with homeomorphic to an open set, but forgot to see its an open set trough homeomorphism